# Magento Product Thumbnail New Tab

Tags: jquery, magento

Hi I have what I feel might be a simple fix but can't figure it out for the life of me.  Currently my magento thumbnails images open in a new window when they are clicked on.  I want to prevent that.  The Thumbnails currently display in the main image area on hover.  The link is below, please help! Thanks

http://glamboutique.com/shop/apparel/liya-h-r-classic-fit-distressed-selvedge.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `<a>` tag value convert `href` attr as href="#" in the `<a>` tag. For example

```
<a href="http://glamboutique.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x1040/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/B/T/BTKA_1469566164493918_c14bb87f38814e5ee435344337dc00_1.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" title="" rel="useZoom:'product-zoom-845', smallImage: 'http://glamboutique.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/560x728/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/B/T/BTKA_1469566164493918_c14bb87f38814e5ee435344337dc00_1.jpg'">
```

to

```
<a href="#" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" title="" rel="useZoom:'product-zoom-845', smallImage: 'http://glamboutique.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/560x728/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/B/T/BTKA_1469566164493918_c14bb87f38814e5ee435344337dc00_1.jpg'">
```

Comment: Tried that, it breaks the cloudzoom feature.